# c# speech recognizer and synthesis

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make a speech recognizer and synthesis . I am new to c#. this code was working perfectly few hours ago... but I don't know what happened then, now it's not working... all the time when I try to run it says  something wrong at the line 36... which is             `reEng.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;



namespace vbot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine reEng = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Choices command = new Choices();
            command.Add(new string[] { "hello", "hi", "say hello", "what is your name?" });
            GrammarBuilder gbuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            gbuilder.Append(command);
            Grammar gramer = new Grammar(gbuilder);
            reEng.LoadGrammarAsync(gramer);
            reEng.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            reEng.SpeechRecognized += ReEng_SpeechRecognized;

        }

        private void ReEng_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
                case "hello":
                    synth.SpeakAsync("\nhello sir, how are you?");
                    break;
                case "hi":
                    synth.SpeakAsync("\nwhat's up, sir?");
                    break;
                case "what is your name?":
                    synth.SpeakAsync("\nmy name is bongo");
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reEng.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit you question to include any error messages? That will help to make it more clear what is happening.

Comment: sorry... but i dont know... im new to programming... :(

Comment: Your questions says `when i try to run its say something wrong at the line 36` - what is it saying? What are the actual words it uses?

Comment: Check to see if you have any other application currently using the default audio device (microphone??) - I would also run task manager to see if all instances of your own application have correctly shutdown sometimes applications may not completely exit - they are not visible but still appear in task manager.